# Fetch Recurring events with google calendar api v3 in php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, recurring-events

I am using google calendar api v3 to fetch calendar events. But how to fetch all the recurring events. It just return single event with some hint like:  DAILY;UNTIL=20 etc. Please help me out with this...

Comment: Please post your code - what have you tried already?

Answer (score 20):

If you are using the Events: list API method, add the `singleEvents=true` parameter. From the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list):

> singleEvents
>
> boolean
>
> Whether to expand recurring events into
> instances and only return single one-off events and instances of
> recurring events, but not the underlying recurring events themselves.
> Optional. The default is False.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer - simple and very accurate. Thanks, +1

Comment: Thanks @rebello95! Glad to be of help.

Comment: It's nice when there's a magic parameter that solves my problem.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, saved me from complicated over-engineered solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If the event is a recurring event. You need to call another function in the API with the event ID and that will then return all the instances.

What does this mean
1) you get a normal even listing from the API.
2) then if you find an event that has ReccurenceID/Recurrence you can call the following with the EVENT ID. You can also specify parameters that you want to just like when searching for normal events (almost)

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId/instances

Here is a nice blog post on it.
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/calendar-v3-best-practices-recurring.html

The google API page is at:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances

Cheers

Peter